# PDF size too large generating through Android PDFDocument. And while using pdfbox it is cutting image in output

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfbox, pdfdocument

I am using android pdf document library to convert image into pdf but it is generating very large size pdf.

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo =new 
PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();                            
PdfDocument.Page  page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), 
bitmap.getHeight(),false);                        

Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
document.finishPage(page);

document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/"+newPDFNameSingle));
document.close();
```

here is the apache pdf box implementation but it is cutting image in output pdf

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
PDImageXObject ximage = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document,inputStream);

contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20);
contentStream.close();

document.save(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/"+newPDFNameSingle);
                            document.close();
```

How can I achieve regular size pdf generation? My image in 100 kb in size but pdf generating 1 mb file.

Comment: `PdfDocument` is for creating PDFs to send to Android's print services. PDF size is not a concern for that scenario. If you want to create PDFs for other purposes, do not use `PdfDocument`.

Comment: I also tried apache pdfbox library but it is cutting down the image after generation image cropped

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited question in which I have tried apache pdfbox library

Comment: In your PDFBox code you should scale the image to fit the page, e.g. by setting the current transformation matrix accordingly before drawing the image, or you should create larger pages.

Comment: Thank you @mkl could you please give me some example

Comment: To scale: `contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth() * scale, pdImage.getHeight() * scale);` with scale being a float value < 1. Please link to the result file and the source JPEG if you're not satisfied with the result.

Comment: What is scale here? I meant what value (float value < 1) is representing

Comment: `1` would be as currently, i.e. 100%. Try values like `0.5f` or `0.25f` and look at the result. You need to try out things to see what happens :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your android pdf document library code you set the page size to the image height and width values

```
PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
```

and draw the image at the origin:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
```

You can do the same in your PDFBox code:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

PDImageXObject ximage = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document,imageResource);

PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(ximage.getWidth(), ximage.getHeight()));
document.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 0, 0);
contentStream.close();
```

*([DrawImage](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/DrawImage.java#L37) test `testDrawImageToFitPage`)*

Alternatively, as discussed in comments, you can set the current transformation matrix before drawing the image to scale it down to fit the page.

Comment: You nailed it bro (Y). By the way Im now using your pdfbox solution. Thank you bro

Comment: @mkl the canvas.drawBitmap in api 28+ gives this error: `Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps`. Do you know to solve?

Comment: Sorry, no, I have not dealt with this recently anymore.